# How to create a Debian/Fedora live USB on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: live-usb, iso, debian, fedora, startup-disk-creator

I tried to use Startup Disk Creator, but it seems that it can only create Ubuntu live disks. Is there any software that can help me create live USB disk for any .iso files? Please also mention how to use that software or provide a link to the guide of using that software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **`mkusb`** in Ubuntu to create USB boot drives for all the major linux distros. And you can use it in many other linux distros to create Ubuntu boot drives. The standard method clones the iso file to a live-only system on the target drive using `dd` under the hood. `mkusb` 'wraps a safety belt' around the powerful but dangerous `dd` tool.

See this link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

There is a list of tested operating systems,

[Linux distros where mkusb works](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Linux_distros_where_mkusb_works)

Answer (score 2):

You could use dd from the terminal.

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sd{device letter here}
```

You can get the device letter by running in the terminal

```
fdisk -l
```

and check which device is your pendrive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the restore disk image option in Disk Utility.

[image]

Unetbootin is also a great tool for making bootable pendrive.

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

After installation, run the software and follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: option has moved/changed in ubuntu 22.04. it is now at the top right. click the 3 dots and click restore image not create image